# Algorithm to determine splitting field of polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I'm thinking about splitting fields and how to determine them in general. I couldn't find any general algorithm to determine the splitting field $L$ of an arbitrary irreducible polynomial $f$ over a field $K$. I could only find algorithms with some restrictions.

Does anyone know, if there is such an algorithm that describes the splitting field $L$ in terms of the minimal polynomial of some primitive element of $L$?

Comment: Factorize $f=\prod_j f_j^{e_j}\in K[x]$, then factorize $f$ in $K_1=K[x]/(f_1)$ and repeat, until $f$ splits completely. For number fields there are algorithms to factorize $f$ based on its factorizations $\bmod p$